# material is not applied to obj file

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to load a 3d object model exported from blender 2.79 in my three JS code using `OBJLoader` and `MTLLoader` libraries. Object is loaded but its material is not applied to it.

Material is shown in cycles render blender properly.

What can i do to apply material to the object file?

The code I am using for this is

```
var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
mtlLoader.load("textures/reception_table.mtl", function(materials) {
    materials.preload();
    var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
    objLoader.load("textures/reception_table.obj", function(mesh) {
        scene.add(mesh);
        mesh.position.set(190, -25, 300);
        mesh.scale.set(4, 6, 4);
    });
});
```

[This is how my model looks in three.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWCqh.png)

Comment: Is there no one who knows how to add material in three js?

Comment: Your code looks fine, but it's hard to tell without seeing a working example. Could be something wrong with your .mtl file.

Comment: I have directly exported file from blender to wavefront (.obj) and there is that .mtl file is generated.

Comment: Try adding 'console.log(materials)' right before the 'setMaterials(materials)' line. What result do you get?

Comment: after adding console.log(materials) i see something like this for every other material inside:

 InsideDoor: {…}
​​​
d: "1.000000"
​​​
illum: "2"
​​​
ka: Array(3) [ 1, 1, 1 ]
​​​
kd: Array(3) [ 0.64, 0.64, 0.64 ]
​​​
ke: "0.000000 0.000000 0.000000"
​​​
ks: Array(3) [ 0.5, 0.5, 0.5 ]
​​​
name: "InsideDoor"
​​​
ni: "1.000000"
​​​
ns: "96.078431"
​​​
__proto__: {…}

Comment: @Marquizzo can you please tell me whats wrong?

Comment: Looks like your .mtl file is wonky, since those properties don't exist in a 'THREE.Material' but its impossible to tell from here. Why don't you upload your files somewhere for others to see whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> What can i do to apply material to the object file?

The syntax for adding the material to an instance of a `Mesh` is

```
myMesh.material = myMaterial
```

In order to add it to the object file though, you could use a text editor and edit the file, or you could try re-exporting it with different settings. There is a possibility that this is not a Three.js problem, but rather a problem with your file. Three.js is probably loading everything the way it's told to.

Comment: As i am new to blender can you tell me which settings i have to change? @pailhead

Comment: I don't use blender unfortunately, i've just given a generic answer from `three.js`'s perspective. There is a possibility that there is a bug with the blender exporter but this is not actually part of three.js, it's just an example that was provided at some point and possibly abandoned.